# Extract part of a string from each item in list of strings (Python)

Tags: python, string, list

Each item in my list of strings looks like this:

```
":"https://www.autoblog.com/2018/10/30/ford-f-150-hennessey-velociraptor-v8-758/"
        },
        {
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":2,
            "
```

I'm just trying to get this part and arrange it in a new list: 
     https://www.autoblog.com/2018/10/30/ford-f-150-hennessey-velociraptor-v8-758/

How do I do that?

```
type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"ItemList",
    "itemListElement":[
        {
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":1,
            "
 ":"https://www.autoblog.com/2018/10/31/2019-ford-mustang-bullitt-review/"
        },
        {
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":2,
            "
 ":"https://www.autoblog.com/2018/10/30/ford-f-150-hennessey-velociraptor-v8-758/"
        },
        {
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":3,
            "
 ":"https://www.autoblog.com/2018/10/30/vw-earnings-beat-expectations-waymo-ford/"
    },
    {
        "@type":"ListItem",
        "position":4,
        "
 ":"https://www.autoblog.com/2018/10/30/ford-gt-carbon-series-lightweight-336hmm9p/"
        },

        {
            "@type":"ListItem",
            "position":17,
            "
":"https://www.autoblog.com/2018/10/23/ford-ranger-bronco-michigan-assembly-plant-history/"
        }
    ]
    } 
 </script>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written in an attempt to do this, and explain what about it falls short.

Comment: Can you post the entire list of strings?

Comment: Done! Posted the entire list.